# How common is it for recruiters to ghost candidates after verbal offer?

Tags: communication, human-resources

I received an email saying that the company in question wanted to make me an offer. I replied back in positive terms and said that I would need to look at the contract.

Almost a month has passed and I haven't heard from them, despite trying to follow up with them multiple times.

Comment: A month is not normal. The only time I had a verbal offer and the offer letter took forever was when I got a job with the US Government as an intern. The manager promised me a position before he officially had funding to do so. It took 2 months to get the official paperwork. Remember to keep interviewing!

Comment: extremely common

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that is not very common from anecdotal evidence.  If you have exhausted your options of callings and emailing then I would save time and move on.

Quick aside, if a recruiter you're working for is bad at communicating and ghosts you, then you shouldn't work with them.  Recruiters and Contractors should be a two way street.  Find yourself a better recruiter.